# how to extract integer from a string? c++

Tags: c++

i have this line taken from a txt file (first line in the file):

```
#operation=1(create circle and add to picture) name X Y radius.
```

why does this code doesnt take the integer 1 and puts it into k?

```
Circle Circle::CreateCirc(Circle c){
    int k;
    ifstream myfile("cmd.txt");
    if (!myfile.is_open())
        cout<<"Unable to open the requested file "<<endl;
    string line,line2="create circle";
    for (int i=1;i<countrows();i++)
    {
        getline(myfile,line);
        if (line.find(line2)!=string::npos)
        {
             istringstream ss(line);
             ss>>k;
             cout<<k<<endl;

        }

    }
    return c;

}
```

instead im getting adress memory...help plz

Comment: Is the number always after the `=`? If so, just take a substring starting one character beyond the `=` and stopping just before the `)`. Feed the resulting string to an `istringstream` and extract an `int` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the line doesn't start with a number. You'll need to skip over the `#operation=` part before extracting a number.

You should check the result of the extraction, and of `getline`, to help identify what's going wrong when these fail.

Also, if `countrows()` returns the expected number of rows in the file, then your loop would miss out the last one. Either loop from zero, or while `i <= countrows()`; or, if you want to process every line in the file, you could simply loop `while (getline(myfile,line))`.

Answer (score 0):

If the actual text in the file you try to read starts with `"#operation=1"` and you want the number `1` from that, you can't use the simple input operator. It will read the character `'#'` first, which isn't a digit and so the parsing will fail and `k` will not be initialized. And if `k` is not initialized, it will be of indeterminate value, and reading that value will lead to undefined behavior and seemingly random output.

You need to check that the extraction worked:

```
if (ss >> k)
    std::cout << k << '\n';
```

That won't solve your problem though, as like I said above, you can't use the simple input operator here. You need to parse the string using other methods. One way might be to find the equal character `'='` and get a sub-string after that to try and extract the number.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: A way to do it not much bit a little closer to the way you were trying to do it using [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) rather than streams.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // for atoi()
int main(){

    std::string str = "#operation=1(create circle and add to picture) name X Y radius.";
    int k;

    std::string line=str, line2="(create circle";

    std::size_t fnd = line.find(line2);
    if (fnd!=std::string::npos)
    {
         k = atoi(&str[fnd-1]); // int atoi(const char *str) == argument to integer
         std::cout<< k << " " << str[fnd-1] << str[fnd] << " ";
    }
}
```

There are a few ways to extract an integer from a string but i like to filter out the digit from the string;

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::string str = "#operation=1(create circle and add to picture) name X Y radius.";
    int k = 0;

    // an array of our base10 digits to filter through and compare
    const char digit[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

    for(int s_filter = 0; s_filter<str.size(); ++s_filter){
        for(int d_filter = 0; d_filter<10; ++d_filter){
        // filter through each char in string and
        // also filter through each digit before the next char

            if(digit[d_filter] == str[s_filter]) {
            // if so the char is equal to one of our digits

                k = d_filter;// and d_filter is equal to our digit
                break;

            } else continue;
        }
    }
    switch(k) {
        case 1:
            std::cout<< "k == 1";
            // do stuff for operation 1..
            return 0;
        case 2:
            std::cout<< "k != 1";
            // do more stuff
            break;
        //case 3: ..etc.. etc..
        default:
            std::cout<< "not a digit";
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `strtol`, which has a more robust interface.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i was using `atoi` only for simplicity, the link to `atoi` provides a link to `strtol` at the bottom of the page if anyone would like a reference to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Circle Circle::CreateCirc(Circle c){
 const std::streamsize ALL = std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max(); // #include <limits> needed
 int k;
 ifstream myfile("cmd.txt");
 if (!myfile.is_open())
    cout<<"Unable to open the requested file "<<endl;
 for (int i=1;i<countrows(); ++i, myfile.ignore(ALL,'\n') ) // skip rest of the line
 {
    if( myfile.ignore(ALL,'=') >> k  )
    {
         cout<<k<<endl;
    }
    else
        break; // read error
 }
 return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// find_num.cpp (cX) 2015 adolfo.dimare@gmail.com
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115457/

#include <string> // std::string
#include <cctype> // isnum

/// Find the number in 'str' starting at position 'pos'.
/// Returns the position of the first digit of the number.
/// Returns std::string::npos when no further numbers appear within 'str'.
/// Returns std::string::npos when 'pos >= str.length()'.
size_t find_num( const std::string str, size_t pos ) {
    size_t len = str.length();
    bool   isNegative = false;
    while ( pos < len ) {
        if ( isdigit(str[pos]) ) {
            return ( isNegative ? pos-1 : pos );
        }
        else if ( str[pos]=='-' ) {
            isNegative = true;
        }
        else {
            isNegative = false;
        }
        ++pos;
    }
    return std::string::npos;
}

#include <cassert>     // assert()
#include <cstring>     // strlen();

int main() {
    std::string str;

    str = "";
    assert( std::string::npos == find_num( str, 0 ) );
    assert( std::string::npos == find_num( str, 9 ) );

    str = "#operation=1(create circle and add to picture) name X Y radius.";
    assert( strlen("#operation=") == find_num( str, 0 ) );

    str = "abcd 111 xyx 12.33 alpha 345.12e-23";
    ///    0123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.
    assert(     5 == find_num( str, 0 ) );
    assert(            13 == find_num( str, 5+3 ) );
    assert(                        25 == find_num( str, 20 ) );

    str = "abcd-111 xyx-12.33 alpha-345.12e-23";
    ///    0123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.
    assert(    4 == find_num( str, 0 ) );
    assert(           12 == find_num( str, 5+3 ) );
    assert(                       24 == find_num( str, 20 ) );

    str = "-1";
    assert( 0 == find_num( str, 0 ) );
    assert( 1 == find_num( str, 1 ) );
    assert( std::string::npos == find_num( str, 2 ) );
    assert( std::string::npos == find_num( str, strlen("-1") ) );

    return 0;
}
```